# Perform Scala ".mkString(_.mkString(","))" equivalent in Gatling Java

Tags: java, string, scala, gatling

I am converting Gatling Scala code to Java. I have a line within a ".check()" which saves a list of students and comma separates them:
`.check(jsonPath("$.students[*].refId").findAll().transform(_.mkString(",")).saveAs("listOfStudents"))`

I am trying to do this in Java but mkString() is used in Scala, not Java. This is the closest I have to it:

`.check(jsonPath("$.students[*].refId").findAll().transform(String.join(",")).saveAs("listOfStudents"))` (note there is no array in the ".join()" since I am not sure where an array would come from here)

Is there a one line solution for this like the Scala original or would this require something more complex using streams which I had suggested to me?

Thanks

Comment: Probably something along the lines of `.transform(array -> String.join(",", array)`, since the original is a function that refers to the array as the `_` placeholder. Note that `String.join` takes a vararg, which in Java is interchangeable with an array. If the collection is not an array you can probably use a `.toArray` method or something analogous.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for is [Collectors.joining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), but still, you will have to convert your `List` into a stream. I'm not sure what you meant by a one-line solution: `String.join` looks like a one-line solution to me.

For example, for this Scala code:

```
  val arr = Array(1, 2, 3)
  println(arr.mkString(", "))             // 1, 2, 3
  println(arr.mkString("( ", ", ", ", ")) // (1, 2, 3)
```

In Java you could do either of these:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
System.out.println(l.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(", "))); 
// 1, 2, 3

System.out.println(l.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(", ", "(", ")"))); 
// (1, 2, 3)
```

Using `String.join` is equivalent to the first `Collectors.joining` above:

```
System.out.println(String.join(", ", l.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(toList()))); 
// 1, 2, 3
```

In fact, Intellij will suggest you to replace this with `Collectors.joining`.
I used static imports, but unfortunately Java is still more verbose either way.